# How to do unit test in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to execute unit test in ruby on rails. I placed my file in test\unit\tab_test.rb

I am able to assert the static text in the page.
Eg:

```
browser.text_field(:name => 'userName').set("bhuvan")
assert(browser.text.include?("Contact US"))
```

I don't know how to assert dynamic (based on condition some text is changing in the page).

Anyone can you help me to assert dynamic text in the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you need to test the UI (Integration Test); normally unit test are for models (to check the application logic).

If I'm correct, please check Capybara or Cucumber for integration testing:

http://techiferous.com/2010/04/using-capybara-in-rails-3/
https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara
http://www.allenwei.cn/cucumber-capybara-what-we-need-for-rails-integration-test/

Answer (score 1):

In general I unit test with rspec and focus on model and controller tests. The key in these things is to always isolate what you are testing from other things with mocks and stubs.

As sameera207 said above I would approach integration tests with something specifically designed to play with the UI. His examples of Capybara and Cucumber are a great place to start.

One caveat I would keep in mind is that I've found cucumber and its technology stack when you use culerity/celerity is very unreliable with javascript intensive apps. We get a lot of spurious timing issue related failures in our ATs everyday and this leads to a lot of triage.